# Getting data from a Github repository when user inputs certain url

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am working with nodejs and was having this problem where the user will input certain url and I should be able to fetch the number of commits, pull etc, done over certain period of time.
Though I think web scraping as a option .
Using npm package caled `**cheerio**.

What will the best way to do this.?
Is there some better way to do this..?
Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Web scraping is a very fragile principle. Your code could be broken every time github changes the page layout of its site.

The right way of doing this is using an API. In this case, the [github API](https://developer.github.com/v3/).